# Process Management in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, process

In my Server/Client setup, I have the Client applications managing other applications on the machine (start/stop/restart/query processes). Right now, I just have a very basic setup using the Process ID, but it occured to me before it goes live, I need to improve this.

If the process stops and another starts using the same ID in between the times that it I issue a query for it, this will whack the system out. None of the processes that I start will ever come from the same file path, but will often times have the same executable name.

I am not having much luck finding it, but can I find the executable path for a running service? I imagine my best bet when querying the running state would be first to look for the stored ProcessID it should be at, if that is running, check the filepath/executable name to make sure it matches as well.

Would there be a better way to do this, or is this the best possible scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Process.Exited`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx) event to be notified when a process you are monitoring exits. This way there will be no chance of things like that happening "while you aren't looking".

Note: for the `Exited` event to be raised, first you have to explicitly set [`Process.EnableRaisingEvents`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents.aspx) to `true`.

Comment: It said that it was too early for me to accept the answer, I was just waiting until that thing went away.

Comment: @David: Sorry then! I saw you were a newbie and thought that maybe you aren't familiar with the site's UI and/or "workflow" yet.